# Does perl have interactive shell?

Tags: perl

Languages like Ruby, Python, Lua, PHP, Node.js, etc. have a simple "shell" where you can type simple one-liners and see the result. Does Perl has something similar? I'm not looking for something fancy that does pretty printing (I'll use print()) or accepts multiline input.

The story is this:

I need to experiment with some regexps. I know I can do `perl -e "..."` but then I need to shell-escape the code and this complicates matters. If I had a Perl shell I wouldn't need to worry about escaping.

Comment: Ok, I see that the question is indeed answered there. Sorry.

Comment: I usually find that using single quotes in -e is good enough for most purposes: `perl -e 'print "my data here\n"'`

Comment: For the specific problem of interactively experimenting with regexps, try `rxrx` from [Regexp::Debugger](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Debugger).

Answer (score 2):

Have a try with this CPAN module:

[Perl::Shell](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl%3a%3aShell)

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever tried `Reply.pm`?  I'm using it.

https://metacpan.org/release/Reply

Comment: Reply is very good. Devel::REPL is also good.